# How to sort by custom column value in WooCommerce admin orders list?

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, orders

I created a column and set its value, but its value is not in the database. The column value comes from an external API.

By using any programming language it is possible to sort an array, etc. But I don't know how to sort the orders list after set the values. I only found ways to sort by post meta.

Custom column:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_set_order_columns' );
function custom_set_order_columns($columns){
    $new_columns = (is_array($columns)) ? $columns : array();
    unset( $new_columns['order_actions'] );
        unset( $new_columns['order_total'] );

    $new_columns['test_button'] = 'Test';
    $new_columns['order_actions'] = $columns['order_actions'];

    return $new_columns;
}
```

Custom column value:

```
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'custom_set_order_column_values', 2 );
function custom_set_order_column_values($column){
  global $post;
  global $api;

  $order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
  $email = $order->get_billing_email();
    
  if ( $column == 'test_button' ) {
    echo $api->getValue($email);
  }
}
```

The normal sort:

```
add_filter( "manage_edit-shop_order_sortable_columns", 'custom_sort_function' );
function custom_sort_function( $columns ) {
  $custom = array(
    'test_button'    => 'POST_META_ID???'
  );
  return wp_parse_args( $custom, $columns );
}
```

I cannot add a post meta to each order because if I do that I need to set the new values in the database after every request.

WordPress Version: 5.5
WooCommerce Version: 4.4.1